# Replace a word from data validation dropdown list to another word not in selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template, where for a column I have list of dropdown say *Active* and *Inactive*.
My requirement is, when I select *Active*, **A** should come and **I** should come for *Inactive*.

Please help. Below is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'if changes in column H and row is > 1 then do the following action

If Target.Column = 8 And Target.Row > 1 Then

'if column D is blank then fill blank in E

If Trim(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)) = "" Then
    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = ""

'Else -'lookup for the respective Legislation_code in Temp Sheet

'and fill in the next column
Else
    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column), Sheets("Ass_status").Range("A:E"), 4, 0)


'Apply Validation/drop-downlist in the next row

    If Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column) = "" Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Copy Destination:=Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column)
        Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column) = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End If
End If
End sub
```

Comment: What dropdown list are you using? And what do you have in mind using. Can you share any relevant info on what you've tried?

Comment: I have a column in my sheet where i put data validation and the list of values are Active and Inactive. I tried using formulae, but i dont know much abt macro. i need macro to replace word witha letter

Comment: If i can use existing excel functions then that too help, if any 1 have idea

Comment: Data validation won't work if you are to change the same cell to reflect A and I instead of Active and Inactive respectively. It can be done with VBA but the approach is not that simple.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'if changes in column H and row is > 1 then do the following action
If Target.Column = 8 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    'if column D is blank then fill blank in E
    If Trim(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)) = "" Then
        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = ""
    'Else -'lookup for the respective Legislation_code in Temp Sheet
    'and fill in the next column

Comment: Else
        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column), Sheets("Ass_status").Range("A:E"), 4, 0)
        
        'Apply Validation/drop-downlist in the next row
        If Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column) = "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Copy Destination:=Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column)
            Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column) = ""
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        
    End If
End If
  end sub

Comment: This way is something we need, its not working

Comment: can we use vlookup? how to use?

Comment: Please edit your question and put your code there instead, not in comments.

Comment: can see the code now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this assuming you have set up your worksheet like below:

[image]

Initially you put validation on *A1* using the list in *B1:B2*.
Then in the same sheet, use below code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo halt        
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim v As String
    If Not Intersect(Target, [A1]) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            v = .Value
            .Validation.Delete
            Select Case v
            Case "Active": .Value = "A"
            Case "InActive": .Value = "I"
            End Select
            .Validation.Add xlValidateList, , , "=$B$1:$B$2"
        End With
    End If
forward:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume forward
End Sub
```

This is tested but only limited number of times. HTH.
Btw, you can be explicit on the validation like this:

```
.Validation.Add xlValidateList, , , "Active,InActive"
```

That way, you don't need a helper cell reference.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i added this code, when i run macro, nothing seems to be worked, can u help?

Comment: @user511 What is not working? What you need to do is change value in A1. That's it. No need to run it since it is an event driven macro.

Comment: Ok. I will check. Thank you so much for your valuable help! Thx.

Comment: @user511 Again you don't put in a Module but on the Sheet Code.

Comment: @user511 And what does not work? Are you working A1 as the code suggest? I just tried it and it works for me. Is your sheet set up as shown above?